# ffmpeg no audio after filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

Could someone help with the disappeared audio?
video_2.mp4 logo3.mp4 - has audio

```
ffmpeg -i video_2.mp4 -i logo3.mp4 -filter_complex \
"color=black:s=1920x1080:d=24 \
,format=yuv444p \
,geq='lum=X*255/W: \
cr=128: \
cb=128' \
[alpha]; \
[0:v]scale=1920x1080, setsar=1[0v]; \
[1:v]scale=1920x1080, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB, setsar=1[1v]; \
[1v][alpha]alphamerge[1v]; \
[0v][1v]overlay=enable='between(t\,11,14)',format=yuv420p [v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a \
-an out.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `-map 1:a -an`, the `-an` negates the mapping. Remove it.